# jquery datepicker with multiple months in vertical column

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I need to display jquery datepicker calendar with multiple months options in vertical column. Looks like next month lies below previous one.
Does any body know, how to do that?

Thank you!

Comment: please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq Welcome to SO....

Answer (score 9):

RTFM:

> **numberOfMonthsNumber**;  Numbrer,Array;  Default:1
>
> Set how many months to show at once.
>   The value can be a straight integer,
>   or can be a two-element array to
>   define the **number of rows and
>   columns** to display.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsbin.com/ewigu/edit

Answer (score 1):

Here you go http://jsbin.com/idavik
Try adding more styles.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for this for a while and I finally found it. You set the 
       .ui-datepicker table { width: 100%;}
        .ui-datepicker.ui-datepicker-multi{width: auto;}
On the jQuery.ui.datePicker.min.css, and I will preface this with I only wanted two months to be stacked or vertical, I set the to 100% and that's it took up the whole space otherwise was not very pretty.

```
   .ui-datepicker-multi-2 .ui-datepicker-group{width:100%}
```

Alas they don't like me so I can't post a pic but it would have been nice for you guys. The stack police at it's best.